# Find last character in a string

Tags: javascript

Write a function called stringLastIndexOf, which accepts two strings: the first is a word and the second is a single character.

The function should return the last index at which the character exists or -1 if the character is not found.

**Do not use the built in String.lastIndexOf() function!**

My code:

```
    let lastOccurrence = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < word.length(); ) {
        if (word.startsWith(char, i)) {
            lastOccurrence = i + char.length() - 1;
            i = lastOccurrence + 1;
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return lastOccurrence;
}
```

Error:
TypeError: word.length is not a function
at stringLastIndexOf:4:26
at eval:16:1
at eval
at new Promise

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?

Comment: And you should iterate backwards from the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

the `.length` property on strings is not a function, it's just a number.

Instead of `word.length()` you probably just need `word.length`

Answer (score -1):

```
}    
    let lastOccurrence = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < word.length; ) {
        if (word.startsWith(char, i)) {
            lastOccurrence = i + char.length - 1;
            i = lastOccurrence + 1;
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return lastOccurrence;
}
```